# How can we implement Proof of Stake on a private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum

I saw a lot of references to PoS but I cannot find any actual reference to implement it. Has someone the link which explains how to implement it on a private blockchain?

Comment: Hi there. The Ethereum implementation isn't ready yet. You could sift through the official research threads and try to piece together an minimal working implementation, but that's almost certainly easier said than done: https://ethresear.ch/ (Either that or have a look at a different chain which already has a running implementation, such as EOS, which uses DPoS.)

Comment: Is EOS production ready now? I mean can it be used to run a real blockchain?